# two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri but I only have one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

There are a lot of questions on this already but in other cases it seems people are trying to have multiple end points. In my case I only have one and only want one endpoint. My error occurs only if I enable Certificate transport security and only on my development machine.

I have a WCF service implemented via the ServiceRoute in MVC:

`RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyServices", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyServices)));`

The entire serviceModel consists of only this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
      <!--<security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>-->          
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When the transport security is commented out it works fine. Uncommenting the transport security results in:

```
A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'https://my.dev.machine.local/MyServices'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.
```

I can take the code and put it in a different environment and it works as expected. WTF?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Visual Studio 2012 RC. Even though I was using VS 2010 having the VS 2012 RC installed caused this problem. Once I uninstalled it this problem was fixed. Just make sure you follow the specific uninstall instructions for 2012 because if you uninstall it using the "Uninstall a program" option in the Control Panel it will break VS 2010 ... I learned the hard way.

Comment: Now one can get a fix from MS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805227 or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805226 depending on your Windows version.